# How to stop moving to intermediate pages without login or after logout?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a session when a condition satisfies. session is being started from index.php page and when the condition satisfies it goes to event.php page and in event.php i have logout.php which destroyed the session and move the page back to index.php page.

My problem is whenever I try to access the event.php page directly without going through index.php I can do so. even after log out I can access page event.php page.

My code index.php

```
if(condition==true){
session_start(); 
header("location:event.php");
}
```

in event.php

```
session_start();
if (session_id()!=null){
load page

}
else{
move to index.php
}
```

in logout.php

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
```

Comment: How do you starting session

Comment: by session_start() function. isn't it correct?

Comment: Sir.. Give name to session like.. $_SESSION['user'] = 'Your_array'

Comment: yes it's working. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: i am comparing session_id() to null in event.php and while logout i am destrying the session. could u please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Probably, with the command 'header("location:index.php");' you go to index.php and start a new session there. If you want login and logout, you should probably use instead of [index, event, logout] -> [login, index, event, logout]

Comment: maybe in the event.php you should use a condition befor session start. If  you don't have a condition, you can just go any time to event.php and start a session

Comment: Or befor you destroy the event, just unset the session_id

Comment: i somehow managed it. created $_SESSION['somevar']='val' in index.php checking it in event.php and destroying it in logout.php. now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

In index.php initialise a session variable as $_SESSION[var]=value

Then in event.php check

```
if (isset($_SESSION[var])){
load page

}
else{
move to index.php
}
```

Comment: still can move to event.php without logging in.

Comment: Create a session variable in index.php and check it in event.php

Answer (score 0):

At the login time when you fetch data array save that in a session variable like

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'your_array_with_user_data';
```

Now check on every page in start like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    //redirect code
}
else{
   //page code
}
```

and destroy session like below

```
session_destroy();
```

or

```
session_unset();
```